# How to get the right output from this python code?

Tags: python

I have a python code, it cannot get the correct output. the code is shown as follows:

```
score = int(input("Please input a score: "))
grade = ""
if score < 60:
    grade = "failed"
elif score < 80:     # between 60 and 80
    grade = "pass"
elif score < 90:
    grade = "good"
else:
    grade = "excellent"

print("score is (0), level is (1)".format(score,grade))
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: `{0}` rather than `(0)` in your print string.

Comment: @Loocid And `{1}` rather than `(1)`.

Comment: @Loocid, Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should change your if statement to:

```
if score <= 60:
    grade = "failed"
elif score <= 80 and score > 60:     # between 60 and 80
    grade = "pass"
elif score <= 90 and score > 80:
    grade = "good"
elif score > 90: #Assuming there is no max score since before, you left the last statement as an else. 
    grade = "excellent"
else: #Not necessary but always nice to include.
    print("Not a valid score, please try again.")
```

And, as @loocid commented, change `print("score is (0), level is (1)".format(score,grade))` to `print("score is {0}, level is {1}".format(score,grade))`

Though I prefer

`print("score is " + str(score) + ", level is " + str(grade))`

Comment: I would downvote the question, but I don't have the reputation to do so, as I am a fairly inactive user (and new, by some standards). :(